# php variable in SELECT query

Tags: php

I have this code below, which should take the $ID passed from a previous page, and build it into the SELECT query:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
echo $id; //THIS RETURNS THE CORRECT ID OF 1
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM list_$id");
```

However, the SELECT code actually translates exactly to this: "SELECT * FROM list_$id" rather than it being the correct syntax of: "SELECT * FROM list_1"

I tried to do this also: SELECT * FROM list_{$id}" and got the same incorrect syntax. How do I get the $id into the SELECT quote correctly?

Comment: The reason it didn't work as you expect is that you need to use string interpolation in order to have the variable render into the string as you expected. Using double quotes (NOT single) you would write "select * from list_{$var}". Single quotes instructs php not to interpolate. Example: http://codepad.org/tNt3w22a

Comment: @SteveAdams the code *does* use double quotes and [the interpolation does work](http://ideone.com/pQYEZ4).

Comment: @user1114503 Please report the *real* code and the *real* results/behavior. That reported results (with the code) are *incorrect*, except if `$id = '$id'`: at least one of the pieces of information provided is not accurate.

Comment: It does not use braces around the variable in your example.

Comment: @SteveAdams Which as my example shows, *it does not need to* use braces.

Comment: Try escaping the underscore `"SELECT * FROM list\_$id"`

Comment: @Fred-ii- The OP seems to be confused and that would lead to the "wrong" behavior (don't ask me how it occurred with the given code): 'However, the SELECT code actually translates exactly to this: "SELECT * FROM list_$id" *rather than it being the correct syntax of*: "SELECT * FROM list_1"'

Comment: @user2864740 OP's going to have to add another variable before the query, assign it to `list_` then concatenate it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- [The OP doesn't need to do that at all](http://ideone.com/pQYEZ4). Using the more verbose `"list_{$id}"` would also work. (Again, the OP is presenting an *incorrect* test-case and reporting the *wrong* result, which is why I awarded a -1 and close vote.)

Comment: @user2864740 I agree with you. I came up with `$id = 1; $var = "list_"; $all = $var.$id; echo $all;` which echos `list_1` - voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

```
"SELECT * FROM list_".$id
```

Comment: Make sure the $id variable is SQL safe, otherwise the code would be open to SQL-injection attacks.

Comment: [The original produces the same result](http://ideone.com/pQYEZ4) (While I suspect the OP *incorrectly* presented the code/result, I gave this a -1 because `"SELECT * FROM list_$id"` produces the same behavior *without* the change to use string concatenation.)

Answer (score 0):

tldr; *the presented test-case and reported result is **incorrect** and does not accurately represent the problem*. Normal [double-quote interpolation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) will work just fine here (however, to prevent possible SQL injection in similar situations, *whitelisting* should be used).

The real problem is likely the usage of *single quotes*, which are not subject to variable interpolation (or various character escapes). Here is [*real* demo code](http://ideone.com/zUlw4q) showing different expressions and the *actual* results.

```
$world = "world!";

echo "Hello_$world\n";         // Hello_world!   (simple interpolation)
echo "Hello_{$world}\n";       // Hello_world!   (if $world can be word-continued)
echo "Hello_" . $world . "\n"; // Hello_world!   (concatenation)
echo 'Hello_$world\n';         // Hello_$world\n (single quotes, no interpolation)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your actually gonna use this on a real site the secure method to do this is

```
$tables = array('list_1', 'list_2', 'list_3',) // And any other possible table names
$id = $_GET['id'];
$tableName = 'list_' . $id;
if (!in_array($tableName, $tables))
{
    // Its not a valid table so quit execution
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM {$tableName}");
```

Never put variables from the client directly into your query